# wxpython: suppress/disable hover-over popup window with listctrl

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets, listctrl

In `listctrl`, if the text in a cell is longer than the width of the cell, only a portion of the text will be visible. When I position the mouse cursor on top of said cell, a small pop-up window will show up in an attempt to display the full text (see screenshots below). **I wonder if there is a way to suppress/disable this behavior.**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This tooltip is shown by the native control when the `LVS_EX_LABELTIP` extended style is used and is, IMHO, very useful, as it's impossible to see the contents of an over long cell without resizing the entire column without it. Because of this, it's enabled by default and as it's something very MSW-specific, wxWidgets API provides no way to disable it.

If you really, really need to do it, you can always use MSW-specific code and do something like (warning: untested code) this:

```
#ifdef __WXMSW__
    HWND hwndList = (HWND)listctrl->GetHandle(); 
    LPARAM style = ::SendMessage(hwndList, LVM_GETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE, 0, 0);
    ::SendMessage(hwndList, LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE, 0, style & ~LVS_EX_LABELTIP);
#endif
```

Comment: If you can show a way to **enable** the ToolTip for ``DataViewCtrl`` there is for sure a bounty from my side :)

Comment: @nepix32, Are you talking about MSW or GTK/Cocoa?

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific: I mean ToolTip for ``DataViewCtrl`` for MSW.

Comment: No, only the native control shows such tooltips, it would be nice to have them for wxDVC, but we'd need to implement them ourselves. It certainly is doable but equally certainly not done yet.

Comment: @nepix32 this would certainly be great to have in the control. At there moment there are some hints how to implement something in a derived class here: https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=41094&p=166052&hilit=wxdataviewctrl+tooltip#p166052 but some platform specific extras are also needed. If you would like to discuss further, I suggest you start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataViewListCtrl` instead, which lacks this useful feature (ToolText when line is ellipsized). As far as I know it is not a dropin for `ListCtrl`, therefore the syntax to use it will be different.